# Calling SuperLU via Intel Visual fortran Windows

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, fortran, linker-errors, intel-fortran

I have created static Library SuperLU 5.3 via Intel Visual Fortran (Intel Parallel Studio Windows) -->  SuperLU.lib.
Source = https://github.com/xiaoyeli/superlu/archive/refs/tags/v5.3.0.zip

It is c based.

I want to test it to call it with Fortran subroutine,
`f77_main.f` with `hbcode1.f`
Since it needs one of BLAS functions `dtrsv.c`, I use MKL instead.
And it need also `c_fortran_dgssv.c` to be compiled first. I compiled with `icx/c c_fortran_dgssv.c`,
and I got `c_fortran_dgssv.obj`
when I compiled that `f77_main.f`  `hbcode1.f`  and `superlu.lib` and `c_fortran_dgssv.obj` with MKL `/Qmkl` using cmd console mode or Visual Studio IDE, it still have error linking.

example i try compiled without creating static lib:

```
cd c:\Superlu\SRC
icl/c *.c 
copy *.obj *.h c:\SuperLu\Fortran
cd c:\SuperLU\Fortran
icl/c c_fortran_dgssv.c 
ifort f77_main.f hbcode1.f *.obj /Qmkl

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol C_FORTRAN_DGSSV referenced in function MAIN__     f77_main.obj
```

f77_main.f in Fortran folder v5.3.0.zip

```
program f77_main 
      call c_fortran_dgssv( iopt, n, nnz, nrhs, values, rowind, colptr, 
     $                      b, ldb, factors, info )
```

while c_fortran_dgssv.c in src folder v5.3.0.zip

```
void
c_fortran_dgssv_(int *iopt, int *n, int *nnz, int *nrhs, 
                 double *values, int *rowind, int *colptr,
                 double *b, int *ldb,
         fptr *f_factors, /* a handle containing the address
                     pointing to the factored matrices */
         int *info)
```

Looks like i got linker problem to call C from fortran.
i tried ifort /names:lowercase or  /names:UPPERCASE same problem

Slu_cnames.h on SuperLU src has many symbol for many computer types.

```
#ifndef __SUPERLU_CNAMES /* allow multiple inclusions */
#define __SUPERLU_CNAMES


#define ADD_       0
#define ADD__      1
#define NOCHANGE   2
#define UPCASE     3
#define OLD_CRAY   4
#define C_CALL     5

#ifdef UpCase
#define F77_CALL_C  UPCASE
#endif

#ifdef NoChange
#define F77_CALL_C  NOCHANGE
#endif

#ifdef Add_
#define F77_CALL_C  ADD_
#endif

#ifdef Add__
#define F77_CALL_C  ADD__
#endif

#ifdef _CRAY
#define F77_CALL_C  OLD_CRAY
#endif
...
```

Comment: Please see [mcve].

Comment: I need HOWTO to use SuperLU in Intel Fortran Windows Environment. Calling the SuperLU from Fortran.

Comment: This site is not very good for posting generic HOWTOs, but it is very good in solving specific problems. That is why we need as many details about what you are doing before getting the error as possible. Often it needs making a small code example and specific compiler commands that generate the error with the code.

Comment: updated detailed problem

Comment: Please show the complete settings. Please show more code for your main Fortran program. It seems you somehow disable the normal name mangling. In that case you would need `call c_fortran_dgssv_` but it is better to fix your setting. Really,,we need the exact specific details, not just a few lines. A real [mcve].

Comment: the source is  https://github.com/xiaoyeli/superlu/archive/refs/tags/v5.3.0.zip in directory source. i dont use any setting yet on console cmd. just use icl/c and ifort without any optimization or options. The name mangling i think on slu_Cnames.h on those zip

Comment: You surely have some options selected in Visual Studio. We need more code of your main program and we need it **in your question**, not in an external link. Did you try my last suggestion? If not, do it now.

Comment: there is no code that i add on. the superlu source only. regarding the option i selected at Visual studio is all default, except MKL library is checked. i also done without visual studio ide. only command console as above

Comment: there is Slu_names.h that contains 
#define c_bridge_dgssv_ c_bridge_dgssv__
#define c_fortran_sgssv_ c_fortran_sgssv__
#define c_fortran_dgssv_ c_fortran_dgssv__
#define c_fortran_cgssv_ c_fortran_cgssv__
#define c_fortran_zgssv_ c_fortran_zgssv__

Comment: Never put code in the comments. [edit] your question and make a full consistent [mcve]. You must show your `f77_main.f` in full, not just 2 lines. Did you **really** try my suggestion about `call c_fortran_dgssv_`? If not why? Please read something about how this undescoring works because you will have to be able to navigate in this mess yourself.

Comment: Alternatively, look if you enabled `/assume:nounderscore` somewhere and disable it. But we really cannot tell you more without seeing your actual settings, you have learn how to deal with those settings in Visual Studio yourself or use some scripts that you can share.

Comment: Problem Solved. removed if on the slu_cnames.h  Use the uppercase only while building superlu with intel compiler

Answer (score 0):

For compiling with Intel compiler (without Makefile) in windows using Visual Studio or command prompt. It need to remove the symbol that compatible to fortran.
Modified slu_Cnames.h is needed compile SuperLu library.

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**
i see slu_cnames.h on superlu c header source code. i need to removed if symbol calling unnecessary method. use the appropriate only, the original "ifmethod" is not worked.  Here is the approriate slu_cnames.h for intel compiler windows.

go to src, edit slu_cnames.h accordingly.

```
/* slu_cnames.h */
#define __SUPERLU_CNAMES

/* BLAS */
#define sswap_    SSWAP
#define saxpy_    SAXPY
#define sasum_    SASUM
#define isamax_   ISAMAX
#define scopy_    SCOPY
#define sscal_    SSCAL
#define sger_     SGER
#define snrm2_    SNRM2
#define ssymv_    SSYMV
#define sdot_     SDOT
#define saxpy_    SAXPY
#define ssyr2_    SSYR2
#define srot_     SROT
#define sgemv_    SGEMV
#define strsv_    STRSV
#define sgemm_    SGEMM
#define strsm_    STRSM

#define dswap_    DSWAP
#define daxpy_    DAXPY
#define dasum_    DASUM
#define idamax_   IDAMAX
#define dcopy_    DCOPY
#define dscal_    DSCAL
#define dger_     DGER
#define dnrm2_    DNRM2
#define dsymv_    DSYMV
#define ddot_     DDOT
#define dsyr2_    DSYR2
#define drot_     DROT
#define dgemv_    DGEMV
#define dtrsv_    DTRSV
#define dgemm_    DGEMM
#define dtrsm_    DTRSM

#define cswap_    CSWAP
#define caxpy_    CAXPY
#define scasum_   SCASUM
#define icamax_   ICAMAX
#define ccopy_    CCOPY
#define cscal_    CSCAL
#define scnrm2_   SCNRM2
#define cgemv_    CGEMV
#define ctrsv_    CTRSV
#define cgemm_    CGEMM
#define ctrsm_    CTRSM
#define cgerc_    CGERC
#define chemv_    CHEMV
#define cher2_    CHER2

#define zswap_    ZSWAP
#define zaxpy_    ZAXPY
#define dzasum_   DZASUM
#define izamax_   IZAMAX
#define zcopy_    ZCOPY
#define zscal_    ZSCAL
#define dznrm2_   DZNRM2
#define zgemv_    ZGEMV
#define ztrsv_    ZTRSV
#define zgemm_    ZGEMM
#define ztrsm_    ZTRSM
#define zgerc_    ZGERC
#define zhemv_    ZHEMV
#define zher2_    ZHER2

/* LAPACK */
#define dlacon_   DLACON
#define slacon_   SLACON
#define icmax1_   ICMAX1
#define scsum1_   SCSUM1
#define clacon_   CLACON
#define dzsum1_   DZSUM1
#define izmax1_   IZMAX1
#define zlacon_   ZLACON

/* Fortran interface */
#define c_bridge_dgssv_ C_BRIDGE_DGSSV
#define c_fortran_sgssv_ C_FORTRAN_SGSSV
#define c_fortran_dgssv_ C_FORTRAN_DGSSV
#define c_fortran_cgssv_ C_FORTRAN_CGSSV
#define c_fortran_zgssv_ C_FORTRAN_ZGSSV
```

then compile and test SuperLU

```
icl /c *.c /O3
lib *.obj /OUT:superlu53.lib /NODEFAULTLIB /INCLUDE:colamd.h /INCLUDE:f2c.h /INCLUDE:slu_cdefs.h /INCLUDE:slu_Cnames.h /INCLUDE:slu_dcomplex.h /INCLUDE:slu_ddefs.h /INCLUDE:slu_scomplex.h /INCLUDE:slu_util.h /INCLUDE:slu_sdefs.h /INCLUDE:slu_zdefs.h /INCLUDE:superlu_enum_consts.h /INCLUDE:supermatrix.h /VERBOSE /NODEFAULTLIB /MACHINE:x64
icl /c c_fortran_dgssv.c /O3 /NODEFAULTLIB 
ifort f77_main.f hbcode1.f superlu53.lib /O3 /Qmkl
```